# database for android application using python+kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, database, kivy

I want to create an application for Android, and for the beginning I decided to create shopping list application.
for example:
I want to make a new list, with 3 ice cream and 2 apples.
Now, I want to syncronize my app with the app in the phone of my wife, so if my wife open her app, she is seeing the list that I created, and she can to add or remove from the list. 
What database I need using and how it's working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Python` and `Kivy` to build the application and use `Firebase` to store the information.